# Can I use a portable monitor with my Acer One and completely detach the laptop lid/screen ?

Tags: display

My screen is broken/cracked on my Acer Aspire one. One hinge is gone. It is a mess. Can I buy a Toshiba 14" USB monitor, hook it up, and completely remove the lid from my laptop, snipping the wires, and tossing it in the trash.I am concerned that the monitor will quit working after I clip the wires/cables that go to the original screen.

Comment: Don't 'snip' wires! There will be a way of removing the cables, or at least cutting them back and making them safe then 'hiding' them within the chassis.

Answer (score 2):

Careful... You can short something out, and/or if you have a webcam, it will no longer work.

USB monitors usually require a driver and are not straight forward to work.

I would advise getting a standard monitor which should do exactly what you want (and be cheaper).

That being said, you may want to search eBay, you can probably find a second hand Acer One for cheaper than the cost of a new monitor!